# Unable to get AutoGenerated ID in MySql JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to get an autogenerated Id after performing an insert operation. I have a table called sg_InsuranceInfo, and it generates an autoIncremented id. So I need to get it. I have attached sample code for reference

```
try
{
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO sg_InsuranceInfo(Patient_Name,LIC_Name) VALUES(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnectionObject().getConnection().prepareStatement(insertQuery,  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, insuranceInformation.getPatientName());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, insuranceInformation.getLicName());
    int noOfRowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    if (noOfRowsAffected != 0)
    {
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(resultSet.next())
        {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1));
        }
    }
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the error text

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.tds.TdsConnection.prepareStatement(Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;
at hospitalApp.common.InsuranceObject.saveInformation(InsuranceObject.java:42)
at hospitalApp.common.InsuranceObject.updateInformationToDatabase(InsuranceObject.java:161)
at hospitalApp.common.InsuranceController.actionPerformed(InsuranceController.java:117)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: You might like to post the whole exception, message and stack trace and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does the job

```
public void saveInformation(InsuranceInformation insuranceInformation)
{       
    try
    {
        int noOfRowsAffected = getConnectionObject().getStatement().executeUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO sg_InsuranceInfo(Patient_Name,LIC_Name) VALUES(" + "'" + insuranceInformation.getPatientName() + "','" + insuranceInformation.getLicName() + "'"
                        + ")");
        if (noOfRowsAffected != 0)
        {
            ResultSet autoGeneratedId = getConnectionObject().getStatement().executeQuery("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
            if(autoGeneratedId.next())
            {
                System.out.println(autoGeneratedId.getInt(1));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can get further information here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 1):

[AbstractMethodError.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled

I suspect that you may be using different version of JDBC jar file for compiling and running your program as this happens only on runtime.

Comment: can you please tell me from which version this supports

Comment: it means that your JDBC driver's dosent support method `prepareStatement(insertQuery,  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`. You may to use newer version of MYSQL jdbc type 4 driver.